# How to write script instead of function in pl/pgsql?

Tags: scripting, plpgsql

I know how to define functions in pl/pgsql ... but (for testing purposes) I would now like to write pl/pgsql as a script. (That is, the code should not be enclosed in a function.) Somehow this does not seem possible. I get syntax errors for things I know are correct (inside a pl/pgsql-function), for example:

```
declare v_test character varying;
```

Even this simple one-line script fails.

How can I write a pl/pgsql script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL parser doesn't support PLpgSQL. PLpgSQL can be parsed (executed) only inside functions (procedures) or inside anonymous block - statement `DO`

```
DO $$
DECLARE x int DEFAULT 10;
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE '%', x;
END;
$$;
```

There are not any other possibility.